# Can Shoes.rb Create Self-Contained Applications?

Tags: ruby, user-interface, macos, distribution, shoes

It's encouraging that Shoes (the Ruby GUI framework) has excellent packaging functionality, but I'm concerned that it doesn't actually 'wrap' itself around created applications. Packaging for OSX outputs a shoes installer and a shoes file in a .app system. Is there any way that shoes could create a .app that contains shoes - that doesn't make you install shoes to run it?

I'm working on creating a tiny application - just a start button and a stop button for a subprocess, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hey, sorry I didn't see this question sooner.

I have good news, and I have bad news: you can absolutely do this, but there's no documentation, currently.

Hackety Hack is the biggest program that does exactly that: http://github.com/hacketyhack/hacketyhack

If you check out the build instructions, you run `rake APP=/path/to/app` and then `rake APP=/path/to/app installer` to build your own binary... but you'll have to do a bit of digging into the Rakefile to figure it out. I *think* that app.yaml is the only thing that's needed.