# Including Shoes in Shoes package

Tags: ruby, windows, pack, shoes

I've been having a problem with including Shoes in a Shoes app for Windows. The packager tool works perfectly when I don't ask to include Shoes in the app: I get an `.exe` that, if launched on a Shoes-less computer, downloads Shoes and then runs as expected.

However, when I ask it to include Shoes, the packager seems to get stuck on something from the get-go. At least, in [some other cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365362/ruby-shoes-packager-including-shoes-in-the-app), the packager does make an executable, even if it didn't contain Shoes. Here, it just freezes.

I even tried the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252412/can-shoes-rb-create-self-contained-applications), but I couldn't manage building shoes. After cloning the `rubyinstaller` repository and downloading the requisite elements, the `rake` command aborts prematurely.

Comment: Can you provide the `rake` logs/output?

Comment: Is the app that you're trying to include Shoes in, by chance, also named "Shoes"?

Answer (score 1):

**Installer** may be a corrupted one
or may contains some missing files.
So,its better to download another and try again.

Answer (score 0):

May be installer itself is buggy. Try other packaging software. The great one for Windows is NSIS [here](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page).
It has a simple scripting which will help you to make your installer more adaptive.

And you could search an old version of this product.